# colcon build --symlink-install failed please help

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cmake error at cmakelists.txt:21 (find_package): by not providing "findcontrol_toolbox.cmake" in cmake_module_path this project has asked cmake to find a package configuration file provided by "control_toolbox", but cmake did not find one. could not find a package configuration file provided by "control_toolbox" with any of the following names:

control_toolboxconfig.cmake
control_toolbox-config.cmake

add the installation prefix of "control_toolbox" to cmake_prefix_path or set "control_toolbox_dir" to a directory containing one of the above files. if "control_toolbox" provides a separate development package or sdk, be sure it has been installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403613/colcon-build---symlink-install-failed-please-help/) by [RahulDas](https://answers.ros.org/users/110340/rahuldas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake can't find `control_toolbox`.

Have you installed `control_toolbox` (`sudo apt install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-control-toolbox`) or is [control_toolbox](https://github.com/ros-controls/control_toolbox) cloned in the source workspace that you are trying to build?

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1